# When booting into Win10 install media, c: changes to e:

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, mbr, ntoskrnl.exe

i've been having some Win10 issues lately.  Some windows updates were installed, and when the PC started back up it gave me the Unexepected I/O error.  Hit enter to try again gave me NTOSKRNL.EXE was corrrupt or missing, then enter again said Hal.dll as missing or corrupt.  It actually booted after that, but it's doing this every time I try to start now.  So I think something is wrong with the boot record.

So I put in the Win10 install disk and boot to that, try the startup repair but it says it can't help.  I then try the various bootrec commands.  However, I notice that when I'm in the command prompt, the c: isn't my normal C:, it's my storage drive.  My C drive is sitting at E:  Anyone know why this is, and if it's a major problem?  When I finally do get into windows, my C: is C:, so i'm very confused.  Also does this sound like a boot record problem, and how should I fix it.

*update*

just rebooted again and got an error with windows\system32\config\system
also windows\system32\winload.exe and windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys

The most odd part is I can load into windows eventually after hitting Enter a number of times.

Comment: That is normal.

Comment: The different drive letters?  ok, so what about the rest of the errors then?

Comment: You have corrupt system files.

Comment: How do I fix that?

Comment: "then try the various bootrec commands. However, I notice that when I'm in the command prompt" doesn't tell us what commands you used

Comment: bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /rebuildbcd
bootrec /fixboot

bootsect /nt60 sys gave an error about not having access

Comment: Edit your question.

Comment: multiple issues here, can't figure out which one comes first ! my advice, login into windows, and then perform a clean boot and check again on your system then update your post with the results :  http://www.thewindowsclub.com/what-is-clean-boot-state-in-windows